# Will only print empty list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, io, append

I am iterating through a .txt file and trying to find the palindromic phrases in it, but when I run this it only prints an empty list.

```
file = open("dictionary.txt", "r")# Load digital dictionary as a list of words

def find_palingram():
    palingram_list = [] # Start an empty list to hold palingrams
    for word in file: # For word in list
        word = word.split()
        end = len(word) # Get length of word
        rev_word = word[::-1]
        if(end > 1):#If Length > 1
            for i in range(end): # Loop through the letters in the word
                """If reversed word fragment at front of word is in word list and letters after form a
                palindromic sequence"""
                if(word[i:] == rev_word[:end-i] and rev_word[end-i:] in file):
                    palingram_list.append(word, rev_word[end-i:])#Append word and reversed word to palingram list
                """If reversed word fragment at end of word is in word list and letters
                before form a palindromic sequence"""
                if(word[:i] == rev_word[end-i:] and rev_word[:end-i] in file):
                    palingram_list.append(rev_word[:end-i], word) # Append reversed word and word to palingram list
    return palingram_list
    file.close()
# Sort palingram list alphabetically
palingram = find_palingram()
palingram_sorted = sorted(palingram)
print(palingram_sorted)
print(file.read())
```

Comment: btw, you should really pass the file into the function and not rely on file being a global. Also file.close() will never execute since it is in the function, but after the return.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a word is a palindrom is really easy:

```
word[::-1] == word
```

or, if your definition of palindrom included, say, `Eve`:

```
word_lower = word.lower()
word_lower[::-1] == word_lower
```

So, you program could be reduced to:

```
def find_palindroms(text):
    palindrom_list = []
    for line in text:
        for word in line.rstrip().split():
            word_lower = word.lower() # might be unnecessary
            if word_lower[::-1] == word_lower:
                palindrom_list.append(word)
    return palindrom_list 

with open("dictionary.txt", "r") as file:
    print(find_palindroms(file))
```

Comment: Would this catch words ending by a comma/dot/question mark etc for example?

Comment: Unfortunately no, since the split() function only splits on spaces all the punctuation is left in and will fail the matching test.

Comment: I already wrote something that does this, I need to find a second word within it and this doesn't do that.

Comment: @quamrana fixing this is trivial, using `word.strip(string.punctuation)`

Answer (score -1):

you should pass the file between the function .Also file.close() will close the file and will never execute since it is in the function..